# concurrent writes of unique values to a java HashSet

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I wonder if it is thread-safe to use a concurrent `HashSet` in Java in which concurrent writes from more than 1 threads can occur if **we can guarantee that each thread can add()/remove() only a unique value**

*for example, a thread can add()/remove() to/from a the `HashSet` its own id)*

I have read that in any case when there are concurrent writes in a `HashSet`, it is not thread-safe **but** I do not understand why is that true in my previous example. **Since each thread can add()/remove() only a unique value (like threadID) which is not going to be added or removed from another thread and as a result there are no dependencies between the threads insertions and deletions, why is not that thread-safe?**

Finally, is there **any more intelligent way** to implement this instead of creating a `ConcurrentHashMap` which contains keys with empty values?

EDIT: I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap) but my question still is not answered. I do not understand why the `HashSet` can be affected by concurrent writes of **different** values.

Comment: Maybe you can use the info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap).

Comment: Please read carefully my question.

Comment: Why? Because [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) says so. It might be the case that concurrent writes *don't* cause problems, but there is no guarantee of that behaviour, so it should not be relied upon.

Comment: This would be clearer if you posted the important parts of the code you are talking about.

Comment: If you do not understand why HashSet is not thread safe, you do not understand the basics of thread safety. Any useful answer to this question would amount to a tutorial.

Comment: I thought I had explained well the above example.
Any thread can execute only
`set.add(ownId)` or `set.remove(ownId)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249714/when-is-copyonwritearrayset-useful-to-achieve-thread-safe-hashset

Comment: What is wrong with using a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: I did not say that it is wrong at all. I just don't like the idea of using a `HashMap` of empty values instead of a `HashSet` (because `ConcurrentHashSet` is not provided)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet`, and `HashMap`, use a hashing mechanism to determine which bucket to put the new entry in. Generally, this will not be affected by parallel access so long as the keys are distinct.

Bucket sizes are carefully observed because if they start getting large, performance takes a significant hit. When a `HashSet`'s bucket gets too full a [resize](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.resize%28int%29) is triggered. This rearranges all of the buckets into a better arrangement.

If another thread attempts to write/read **during** a `resize` is is very likely that the process will crash as the structure is in the midst of being rearranged.

If normal synchronisation mechanisms seem too onerous you may be better to use a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354623/823393) for some usage hints.

Comment: That's a nice answer! Thank you!

Comment: This answer suggests that it will be OK to modify the HashSet concurrently. That is plain wrong.

Comment: No, it points the exact problem that can occur. Read more carefully the  3rd part.