# Insertion order in CopyOnWriteArraySet VS HashSet

Tags: java, copyonwritearraylist

Everyone knows `HashSet` stores elements in **buckets** based on the size of the hashtable and the elements' hash code values.

But how does `CopyOnWriteArraySet` store elements? I thought it makes a snapshot of those buckets and copies them. Looks like it doesn't. Does it store them in 'normal' array 1 by 1 and checks `equals()`?
Does it even use hashing principle?

Comment: [Looks like](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.java) it's just a wrapper for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` which uses plain array storage.

Answer (score 1):

[`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) is a `Set`-wrapper for [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which stores its elements in an array, so it does not use hashing. That's why it doesn't have the O(1) lookup benefit of a HashSet.

The docs say it is only suitable for small sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know why they sticked with CopyOnWriteArrayList implementation? Couldn't they make something like a copy on HashSet for modifications? In that case we would have lookup benefit as well as elements would be copied into hashtable snapshot. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know why anyone made any particular decision, but have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720396/different-types-of-thread-safe-sets-in-java) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29249714/3890632) discussing when CopyOnWriteArraySet is useful.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know when to use it. I am curious of why store its snapshot in plain array instead of buckets..

Comment: If "when to use it" specifies "only when really small sets are involved", that would be the reason that it is practical to use plain array storage instead of a hashtable.

Comment: True, makes sense. Looking on memory perspective, it would also take less space, right? Because if it had used CopyOnWriteHashSet, it would need to store entire hashtable + linkedList on each bucket, am I right?

Comment: It would need to store a more complex structure, and there would be more overhead if the whole structure is supposed to be copied each time an element is added.