# Is there any threadsafe class for Set

Tags: java, list, dictionary, set

We have Vector for List, and Hashtable for Map.

Similarly do we have any class which has thread safe methods for Set?

Comment: `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, `CopyOnWriteArraySet` - both documented

Answer (score 6):

One option: (java8)

```
Set<String> set = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
```

which is similar to HashSet, but also safe to use concurrently.

Comment: almost the same as `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054517/concurrenthashmap-newkeyset-vs-collections-newsetfrommap

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to get thread safe sets. some e.g.

1. CopyOnWriteArraySet
2. Collections.synchronizedSet(Set set)
   etc

Check this for more details - [Different types of thread-safe Sets in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720396/different-types-of-thread-safe-sets-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

`Vector` and `Hashtable` are relics from before the Collection framework was introduced, and should be avoided if possible. The "new" way is to either use a specialized collection from the `java.util.concurrent` package, or to make a normal `List` / `Map` / `Set` and then use the `Collections.synchronized...` utility to make them synchronized. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-

Remember to synchronize when using the iterator for objects obtained using `Collections.synchronized...` as the iterators are not synched and manual synch is required. Without any synchronization can lead to `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Collections.synchronized... are less efficient than specialized concurrent data structures since they are simply wrappers that synchronize on *every* call. It is better to use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentFoo` when possible.