# ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet() vs Collections.newSetFromMap()

Tags: java, set, java-8, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Java 8 introduced new way to obtain a concurrent `Set` implementation

```
// Pre-Java-8 way to create a concurrent set
Set<String> oldStyle = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
// New method in Java 8
Set<String> newStyle = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
```

Is there any reason to prefer new method?

Any advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: It's shorter...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` should be somewhat more efficient as removes a single level of indirection. `Collections.newSetFromMap(map)` is mostly based on redirecting the operations to the `map.keySet()`, but `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` is very close to `map.keySet()` itself (just with additions support).

As for functionality, I see no difference.

Comment: *"just with modifications support"* meaning the ability to *add*? Because keysets always had remove support.

Comment: `as removes a single level of indirection` - are you sure? As I can see KeySetView still delegates its method to internal map.

Comment: @turbanoff, `KeySetView` delegates its methods to the map, but `newSetFromMap` first delegates its methods to the keySet methods, which in turn delegates them to the map. That's why it's one indirection level less.

Answer (score 17):

`ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` is just a part of a feature which is much broader than `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`.

The difference becomes clear if you look at this example:

```
Set<String> set=new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>().keySet("hello");
```

Instead of mapping to `Boolean.TRUE` you are now adding the value `"hello"` when adding a new value to the `Set`.

That’s why the returned `Set`s have the type [`ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html). This type has additional methods for [asking for the backing map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html#getMap--) as well as [which value will be used when adding new keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html#getMappedValue--).

---

So while `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` looks like doing the same as `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`, there is the semantic difference that the latter says you shouldn’t use the map afterwards while the former is part of a feature which is designed to interact with the map.

See [`Collections.newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-):

> The specified map must be empty at the time this method is invoked, and should not be accessed directly after this method returns.

In fact, it is not even specified that `Collections.newSetFromMap` will use `Boolean.TRUE` for added values—you should never deal with that anyway…

---

It might also be useful when you wan to pass the `Set` to code which explicitly requests a `ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView`.

---

If you are using the result using the compile-time type `Set` only, there is still the possibility that code which receives that `Set` will use `instanceof`/type casts to find out that the result of `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` is backed by a `ConcurrentHashMap` while the result of `Collections.newSetFromMap` won’t tell you. On the other hand, that also allows code to do unintended things with backing map that way…

Comment: While that's true, I don't see how this feature can be useful with `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: I added a note which should make it clear.