# Why keySet() in ConcurrentHashMap returns KeySetView and not just Set like other Map implementations?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, keyset

Why `keySet()` in `ConcurrentHashMap` returns `KeySetView<K,V>` and not just `Set` (since Java SE8)?

```
ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView<K,V>   keySet()
```

> [KeySetView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html#method.summary) - A view of a ConcurrentHashMap as a Set of keys, in which
>   *additions may optionally be enabled* by mapping to a common value.

But `keySet()` does not enable "mapping to a common value" (unlike `keySet(V mappedValue)`) so I don't see any sense in making it `KeySetView<K,V>` - `boolean add(K e)` and `boolean   addAll(Collection<? extends K> c)` methods would always throw `UnsupportedOperationException` here.

P.S. I know that `KeySetView<K,V>` *extends (is-a)* `Set<K>`. So I can use Set interface as usual.

I also understand that keySet() is free to return whatever class it likes to the Set interface (and we shall not care), but in ConcurrenthashMap that return class is explicitly documented - seemingly for some useful purpose.

**Maybe the only use-case here is that `KeySetView<K,V>` gives access to the backing map**:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>  getMap()
```

Comment: Wouldn't your point about `add(K e)` etc. throwing `UnsupportedOperationException ` be moot since `Set<K>` already provides those methods? Thus even a normal key set would have to implement those methods in the same way.

Comment: Between Java 7 and Java 8, the `ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()` method did change from returning `Set<K>` to returning `ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView<K,V>`.
This is a covariant override, since `KeySetView<K,V>` implements `Set<K>`.  The question can be stated as why this did change in `java 8`.

Comment: If the designer/implementors don't post here, someone would have to dig into the code to answer the question

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  chm.put("one", 1);
  chm.put("two", 2);
  
  Set<String> set = chm.keySet();
  
  set.add("three"); // UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: some related discussion on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054517/concurrenthashmap-newkeyset-vs-collections-newsetfrommap