# How can I fix the issue of an Object being added twice to a Set because of Multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, set, hashset, java-threads

So I'm having this issue with my HashSet.

I am modyfing it from the Main-Thread and the FX8-Thread and now some Objects were added twice. 
Anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Use a thread safe set.  Use `putIfAbsent()`.

Comment: Weirdly, Java's concurrent set doesn't have a `putIfAbsent()` method.  So perhaps use a `ConcurrentMap` and just store your elements as a both key and value the same object.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Use `Set<...> mySet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<..., ...>());` . See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap) for a discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet`s are not thread safe.  This somewhat older thread has a good discussion of thread safe sets: [Different types of thread-safe Sets in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720396/different-types-of-thread-safe-sets-in-java)

I'd start by making sure you're using a thread-safe `Set` implementation and then make sure your objects implement `hashcode` and `equals` methods according to what is described here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/